# sqlsrv_num_rows resule Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean give

Tags: php, sql

```
$results = sqlsrv_query($dbconn, $query2, array(), array('Scrollable' => 'static'));
if (sqlsrv_num_rows($results) >= 2) {
    $query3 = "UPDATE ClanDb.dbo.CL SET RegiDate =
    '$today', Cpoint = (SELECT SUM(Point) FROM
    SodDb.dbo.Sod2Clan$yyMM WHERE SodDb.dbo.Sod2Clan$yyMM.
```

How do i fix this one?

Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Clan\sod2.php on line 42

Comment: Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Clan\sod2.php on line 42

Comment: You have an error in your query, so `$results` is `false`. You should check for this and use [`sqlsrv_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

sqlsrv_query returns a statement resource on success and FALSE if an error occurred.

So $results is probably FALSE. Check your $results, you probably do not have db connection established or $query2 is not good.

Check documentation for sqlsrv_query http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php, and then for sqlsrv_num_rows.

Comment: if ($dbconn) {
 $query = "INSERT INTO soddb.dbo.sod2clan$yyMM SELECT
 clandb.dbo.ul.ChName,Point, RegistDay, ClanName FROM
 clandb.dbo.ul, soddb.dbo.sod2record$yyMM WHERE 
 clandb.dbo.ul.ChName = soddb.dbo.sod2record$yyMM.charname
 AND SNo = '$SNo' AND RegistDay BETWEEN '$negtime' AND
 '$addtime'";
 
 sqlsrv_query($dbconn, $query);

Comment: $query2 = " SELECT clandb.dbo.UL.ChName, Point, RegistDay, ClanName
 FROM clandb.dbo.UL, soddb.dbo.sod2record$yyMM WHERE
 clandb.dbo.UL.ChName = soddb.dbo.sod2record$yyMM.charname
 AND RegistDay BETWEEN '$negtime' AND '$addtime' and
 ClanName = (SELECT clandb.dbo.UL.ClanName FROM ClanDB.dbo.UL 
 INNER JOIN soddb.dbo.sod2record$yyMM ON SNo = '$SNo' AND 
 clandb.dbo.UL.ChName = soddb.dbo.sod2record$yyMM.CharName WHERE
 ClanName=(SELECT clandb.dbo.UL.ClanName FROM clandb.dbo.UL INNER 
 JOIN soddb.dbo.sod2record$yyMM ON SNo = '$SNo' AND

Comment: thats my query 2